# HTML list doesn't follow CSS margin rules

Tags: html, css

So I have a code which sets the default margin and padding for the html to 0

CSS:

```
body,html {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    width:100%;font-family:arial;
}
#headingUl li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="heading">
    <ul id="headingUl">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>   
</div
```

...but the lists still has a left margin.

[image]

Comment: `ul` has default `padding-left` so you should remove it.

Comment: If you're hitting a snag with this unexpected formatting you're going to hit more with other html elements that you aren't using now but my use in the future. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ is great resource for understanding how to reset browser specific properties that are applied to html elements.

Comment: I'm accord with you @fauverism the reset method that I propuse is very basic.

Answer (score 2):

```
#headingUl {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Browsers set default ul, ol padding. You need to overwrite it.

You can reset it to all lists to not worry about it again:

```
ul, ol {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, copied too much of your sleector, it needs to be set on list (ul/ol, not li), i've corrected selector.

Comment: but this solution only going to apply on the #headingUl list, if you add another list on your html code, then the problem will appear again.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid this kind of behavior you should reset the automatic styles.

```
*{
   margin:0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Nenad Vracar said, `ul` element has a default `padding-left` or `margin-left` value set to 40px.

See documentation here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Consistent_list_indentation

You need to overwrite it like this :

```
#headingUl { padding-left:0; margin-left: 0; }
```

> In Internet Explorer and Opera, the lists are indented by setting a
>   left margin of 40 pixels on the  element. Gecko, on the other
>   hand, sets a left padding of 40 pixels for the  element

Answer (score 1):

You assigned `padding:0;` and `margin:0;` to the `html` container and the `body` container which will not affect the inner elements so you need to add the following to your styles:

```
ul {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make hard reset all properties using the program created by Eric Meyer - CSS Reset.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

For quick getting rid of useless fill use code below

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```